# Why does referencing the non-declared variable "name" return "result" in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, object, web, jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4j20xkh/)

in the following, the variable name was never declared. The value is returned as the string "result". Isn't this incorrect, shouldn't it be "undefined"?

```js
let obj = {
name: name,
age: "23"
}

alert(obj.name);
```

or

```
obj = {
name,
age: "23"
}

alert(obj.name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because JSFiddle manually injects the following script into *every* iframe:

```
// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
  window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
    height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    slug: "n4j20xkh"
  }], "*")
}

// always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
window.name = "result"
```

You can see this by Inspecting the result iframe, and looking at the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the body. So even though your code doesn't ever create a `name` variable, it already exists in the global scope.

[image]

Note that `window.name` [will *always* exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), as a string, regardless of site, even if the site doesn't assign to it.

(Usually, referencing an un-initialized variable will result in a ReferenceError - *not* `undefined` - but since `window.name` exists, no error is thrown.)

Comment: I can't believe I actually hit the needle in the haystack.

Answer (score 4):

You're just assinging `window.name` (`name` defined on a global scope) to `obj.name`:

```js
let obj = {
name: name,
age: "23"
}

console.log(window.name);
console.log(obj.name);
```